# MaxActive database connection parameter doesn't work

Tags: tomcat, datasource

I have a problem with datasource configuration.

I have a Tomcat 7 with Java 7 and a Quartz web application. 
This application has a datasource configured:

```
<Resource 
   auth="Container"
   driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
   factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
   logAbandoned="true"
   maxActive="3"
   maxIdle="1"
   maxWait="10000"
   name="jdbc/name"
   password="XXXXXX"
   removeAbandoned="true"
   removeAbandonedTimeout="120"
   type="javax.sql.DataSource"
   url="jdbc:mysql://xxxxxx:3306/xxxxx?autoReconnect=true&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&rewriteBatchedStatements=true"
   username="usr"
   validationQuery="SELECT 1" />
```

With maxActive = 3 I expected to see no more than 3 connection opened. Instead of this, I see a new connection opened every time a Quartz Job starts, untill 8 connection (don't know if this is the default limit).

So it seems this parameter is not considered, but other yes, because the connection to database is correct so username, password etc... are ok.

Can you help me please?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I reply to myself

It was a problem of factory org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory

using org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory (replacing the originial tomcat 7 jar) it works

Don't know why, but it works. With org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory even if initialSize was set to 8, only one was instantiated. Simply replacinig with org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory, 8 were instantiated

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you use wrong attribute to set max connections, you should use maxTotal instead of maxActive.

For more information see [BasicDataSource Configuration Parameters](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html)